# Fantasy manga in which the hero is transferred to another world and later his childhood friend and two police officers are transferred

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

Hero is a high school student trained in martial arts by his grandfather with a childhood friend. One day, he is summoned to another world (probably with his katana). His childhood friend is also summoned later, along with two police officers who came to investigate the hero's disappearance. The hero later becomes a noble, but is sent (exiled to keep him in check) to an island where only criminals live.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Was this in full colour or mostly black & white? Also, was the childhood friend male or female?

Answer (score 5):

This is *[Record of Wortenia War](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/record-of-wortenia-war)*, aka *Wortenia Senki*. It is licensed by [J-Novel Club](https://j-novel.club/series/record-of-wortenia-war-manga).

> Ryoma Mikoshiba, **an ordinary high-schooler adept at martial arts, one day finds himself summoned to another world**. The ones who summoned him, the O’ltormea Empire, cite the fact that 'when those summoned kill another living being, they can absorb a fraction of their strength and make it their own' as their reason. But upon learning the empire uses those they summon to strengthen themselves by foul means, Ryoma is consumed by hatred and slays an important member of the O’ltormean court. ...

The main character is summoned to the other world while he's at school, so he doesn't have his katana with him, but an earlier scene does show him dueling with his grandfather, and after being summoned he promptly kills his summoners with their own weapons.

He does eventually become a noble and is exiled. I forget the exact circumstances, but he was given a title due to his important involvement in some political wars, but they also wanted to get rid of him, so they gave him an undesirable territory that he couldn't refuse.

There's some discussion on this in chapter 25.

[image: Discussion on removing him]

The police officers appear in chapter 26 and are transported to another world; following chapters include scenes covering their new adventure. Two police officers visit his grandfather investigating the MC's disappearance. They, the grandfather, and his female childhood friend are summoned to the same world. The grandfather reveals that he had escaped from there and that's why he so diligently trained the MC

[image: Explanation of why MC was trained] [image: Shortly after being summoned]